# I am not getting the correct results

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL please excuse me.

I am trying to report on all SAN LUNS (logical disks) and if they are new or have been extended between 2 dates. I have included my code below. I have something wrong in my logic. I would be greatful for any help you may be able to give me. Thank you in advance.

```
   #OCTOBER SAN CHANGES
    USE ditinfo_devel;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb_1;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb_2;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb_3;

    # LAST LOG FOR PREVIOUS MONTH
    SET @month1start = '2014-08-10 00:00:00'; 
    SET @month1end = '2014-08-10 23:59:59'; 

    # LAST LOG FOR THIS MONTH
    SET @month2start = '2014-10-12 00:00:00'; 
    SET @month2end = '2014-10-12 23:59:59'; 

    CREATE TABLE tempdb_1( 
    lun_name VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    report_date DATE NOT NULL ,
    san VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    lun_raid VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    type_of_change VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    lun_size FLOAT( 10, 2 ) 
    );

    CREATE TABLE tempdb_2( 
    lun_name VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    report_date DATE NOT NULL ,
    san VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    lun_raid VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    type_of_change VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    lun_size FLOAT( 10, 2 ) 
    );

    CREATE TABLE tempdb_3( 
    sumWaAllocatedStorage_GB INT(11),
    sumBaAllocatedStorage_GB INT(11),
    sumAllocatedStorage_GB INT(11),
    lun_name VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    report_date DATE NOT NULL ,
    san VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    lun_raid VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    type_of_change VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    oldlun_size_GB FLOAT( 10, 2 ), 
    new_lun_size_GB FLOAT( 10, 2 ) 
    );

    **# My original code
    INSERT INTO tempdb_1
    # using distinct in case of old luns called the same name and no longer used.
    SELECT DISTINCT(lun_name), report_date, san, lun_raid, "Extended", lun_size
    FROM tbl_san_log
    WHERE date( report_date ) >= @month1start
    AND date( report_date ) <= @month1end
    # Need this in the query
    GROUP BY lun_name;**

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # I have tried the following code which I copied and made change to from this site but now my results are not showing any new lun_name(S) that have been created. 

    INSERT INTO tempdb_1
    SELECT tt.lun_name, tt.report_date, tt.san, tt.lun_raid, "Extended", tt.lun_size
    FROM tbl_san_log tt

    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT lun_name, MAX(lun_size) AS MaxLunSize
        FROM tbl_san_log
        GROUP BY lun_name
    ) groupedtt


    ON tt.lun_name = groupedtt.lun_name
    AND tt.lun_size = groupedtt.MaxLunSize
    WHERE date( tt.report_date ) >= @month1start
    AND date( tt.report_date ) <= @month1end;

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    **# my original code
    INSERT INTO tempdb_2
    # using distinct in case of old luns called the same name and no longer used.
    SELECT DISTINCT(lun_name), report_date, san, lun_raid, "Extended", lun_size
    FROM tbl_san_log
    WHERE date( report_date ) >= @month2start
    AND date( report_date ) <= @month2end
    # Need this in the query
    GROUP BY lun_name;**


    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # I have tried the following code which I copied and made change to from this site but now my results are not showing any new lun_name(S) that have been created. 

    INSERT INTO tempdb_2
    SELECT tt.lun_name, tt.report_date, tt.san, tt.lun_raid, "Extended", tt.lun_size
    FROM tbl_san_log tt

    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT lun_name, MAX(lun_size) AS MaxLunSize
        FROM tbl_san_log
        GROUP BY lun_name
    ) groupedtt


    ON tt.lun_name = groupedtt.lun_name
    AND tt.lun_size = groupedtt.MaxLunSize
    WHERE date( tt.report_date ) >= @month2start
    AND date( tt.report_date ) <= @month2end;

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------


    SELECT SUM(lun_size) INTO @sumWaAllocatedStorage from tempdb_2 
    WHERE tempdb_2.san LIKE  '%wagga%' ;

    SELECT SUM(lun_size) INTO @sumBaAllocatedStorage from tempdb_2 
    WHERE tempdb_2.san LIKE  '%bathurst%';

    SELECT SUM(lun_size) INTO @sumAllocatedStorage from tempdb_2 
    WHERE tempdb_2.san NOT LIKE  'nas%';

    INSERT INTO tempdb_3
# EXTENDED LUNS 
   SELECT @sumWaAllocatedStorage, @sumBaAllocatedStorage, @sumAllocatedStorage, tempdb_2.lun_name, tempdb_2.report_date, tempdb_1.san, tempdb_1.lun_raid, tempdb_1.type_of_change, tempdb_1.lun_size, tempdb_2.lun_size
    FROM tempdb_2
    LEFT JOIN tempdb_1 ON tempdb_2.lun_name = tempdb_1.lun_name
    WHERE tempdb_1.lun_size  <>  tempdb_2.lun_size;

    INSERT INTO tempdb_3
# NEW LUNS    
SELECT @sumWaAllocatedStorage, @sumBaAllocatedStorage, @sumAllocatedStorage, tempdb_2.lun_name, tempdb_2.report_date, tempdb_2.san, tempdb_2.lun_raid, "New", 0, tempdb_2.lun_size
    FROM tempdb_2
    LEFT JOIN tempdb_1 ON tempdb_2.lun_name = tempdb_1.lun_name
    WHERE tempdb_1.lun_name is NULL;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb_1;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb_2;

    SELECT * FROM tempdb_3
```

Comment: Sorry, you have to be much more specific in your question to get an answer. No one is going to dig through all that and _guess_ what your problem might be. Please post only the relevant code, explain in detail what result you get and why that is wrong in your eyes, so what you expected to get. Descriptions like "does not work" or "not getting the correct result2 never help anywhere. _Be specific_.

Comment: I have a table that can have duplicate lun_names and sizes for a specific date. What I need is insert into a temp table (tempdb_1) distinct lun_names and where there is duplicate lun_names select that lun_name with the max lun_size. This is what I have tried to achieve above. Regards.

Comment: INSERT INTO tempdb_1
    SELECT tt.lun_name, tt.report_date, tt.san, tt.lun_raid, "Extended", tt.lun_size
    FROM tbl_san_log tt

    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT lun_name, MAX(lun_size) AS MaxLunSize
        FROM tbl_san_log
        GROUP BY lun_name
    ) groupedtt


    ON tt.lun_name = groupedtt.lun_name
    AND tt.lun_size = groupedtt.MaxLunSize
    WHERE date( tt.report_date ) >= @month1start
    AND date( tt.report_date ) <= @month1end;